# What is the difference between \n and std::endl

Tags: c++, newline, std

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19199067/revisions), today, was edited and `std::endl` was changed to `\n`.

Does `\n` have any advantages?

Comment: Weird, I searched but couldn't find

Comment: Anyway I would mark that edit as invalid. If someone thinks that you should modify the code in your answer, they should have left a comment for you to consider. Modifying your code risks making your answer mistaken, if they are wrong.

Comment: @SJuan76 The code in my answer really doesn't need `std::endl`(It doesn't need to `flush` the `stream`), so I am good with that edit.

Comment: @khajvah Edit it back.  If you wanted `std::endl`, then no one should change it by editing to something you didn't want.  (In general, when answering questions here, `std::endl` is probably better, since it's what is more usually wanted.)

Comment: @SJuan76 I agree.  This is absolutely abuse of editing.  I've had to edit my own back once or twice for similar reasons.

Comment: @JamesKanze It's not about `wanting`. At the time of my answer, I didn't know the difference, so just randomly chose `std::endl`. In case of my answer, it is more reasonable to use `\n` but still, editing to `\n` and commenting `use \n` isn't helpful. Editor should have explained better.

Comment: @khajvah In the context of your answer, `std::endl` is better.  In general, unless there is a specific reason not to, `std::endl` is to be preferred, especially for output which will probably end up on a terminal.  About the only time you want to use `'\n'` is when outputting large quantities of data in a block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::endl` calls `flush` stream while `cout << "\n"` does not flush the stream, so `cout << "\n";` gain better performance, especially while you call it in loop.

§27.7.3.8 **Standard basic_ostream manipulators**

```
namespace std {
template <class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& endl(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os);
}
1 Effects: Calls os.put(os.widen(’\n’)), then os.flush().
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it doesn't flush the stream which can be a huge time burden.

Comment: Can you give me example when We need to flush the stream?

Answer (score 0):

`\n` terminates the line. `std::endl` terminates the line **and** flushes the output buffer. In most cases, continually flushing the output buffer merely wastes time.

Comment: In most cases, _not_ continually flushing the output buffer wastes the developer's time, since it gives a false idea of how far the program has gotten before it crashes.

Comment: @JamesKanze - relying on the wrong tool wastes developer's time. If you need progress reports, by all means flush buffers.